Path not recognised after deployment
In my PromptFlow, I define a path to a file as:
path: str = os.path.join(
    os.getcwd(),
    folder_name,
    sub_folder_name,
    file_name,
)

When I run this in VS Code on my PC [Windows], it finds the file.
When I run this in ai.azure.com, it finds the file.
But if I deploy this PromptFlow, then when I call the endpoint I get the error message:

{
"error": {
"code": "UserError",
"message": "Execution failure in 'my_python_file': (FileNotFoundError) [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/runit/promptflow-ingress/my_folder_name/my_subfolder_name/my_file_name'"
}
}

At runtime, I get it to dump out the files that it finds in os.getcwd() (that is the folder /var/runit/promptflow-ingress/) and it returns:

'handle_executor_containers.py'
'finish'
'run'
'supervise'


Found the answer by getting the application to export a tree view of the folder structure.

/var/azureml-app/azureml-models/{deployment-name}/{model-name-version-number}/model/

